# multiply based on a condition on hardcoded values in pandas python

Tags: pandas

I have :

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
```

my table looks like :

```
ID   value 
a    20 
b    30
c    40
```

Expected table :

```
ID   value   Expected_output
a    20      40
b    30      90
c    40      160
```

I tried using np.where but getting the wrong output. How can I multiply hardcoded a,b,c with values

Comment: Have you tried np.select ? I can't write an answer on my phone :( sorry

Comment: Are your a,b,c values stored in a dictionary or are they a pandas series object?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are `a`, `b` and `c` just normal variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your values `a,b,c` are stored in a dictionary, you can create another pandas series `multiplier` to perform the multiplication

Edit: added map() function thanks to [@filbranden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9447571/filbranden)

```
import pandas as pd
mul_dict = {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 4}

id_col = ["a", "b", "c"]
val_col = [20, 30, 40]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id_col, val_col)), columns=["ID", "value"])

# multiplier is a pandas series
multiplier = df["ID"].map(mul_dict) 

df["Expected_output"] = df["value"] * multiplier
print(df)
```

Comment: Why create an DataFrame and then add columns instead of simply using the constructor for its intended purpose?

Comment: @AMC I created the dataframe to add the input data and for demonstrating the end result

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates to my comment, though?

Comment: @AMC I just wanted to make the answer readable and understable, the actual answer is just a couple of lines of code, but that would be difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

if multiplier is a list you can simply do:

```
data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
multiplier = [2, 3, 4]
data['Expected_output'] = data.value * multiplier
print(data)

#   ID  value  Expected_output
# 0  a     20               40
# 1  b     30               90
# 2  c     40              160
```